# International Broadcast - database programs?

Tags: hf, software, transmitter, international-operating

In my search to identify the stations I can (barely) hear on my small shortwave setup, I discovered the [HFCC](http://www.hfcc.org). They have a tool that takes your location and UTC time, and provides a list of stations that are aimed at my part of the world (ITU zone). the list is sorted by hours of transmission, and lives [here](http://www.hfcc.org/schedule/).

This is very nice, but it's not what I'm after. I'd like a list of **all** broadcasters, on the air at the time I search. I'd like to be able to sort this list, by frequency or by range to Tx station.

Obviously, this is a matter of setting up a query of the HFCC database files. Before I risk re-inventing the wheel, I'm asking: has anyone else made a database app that uses the HFCC data?

**Edit**: This question has been declared "off topic" So I'm amending the question.
What techniques are used to maintain a log (or database) of stations received?
I'm still just starting, so the international broadcasters are easier to chase (known transmit times, known location - range & bearing easy to calculate). Whatever log I use, should be *expandable* for when I get the equipment (and license) to transmit.
Do people still exchange cards when they make a contact, or has that practice fallen out of favor?

Comment: The schedule you link looks like it does list all broadcasters (that HFCC knows about) to me.

Comment: Hi Alan. I'm sorry, but at the moment, this question smells very much of asking both about broadcasting, and "product recommendations" (where the product in this case might be a service). As such, it would be [off topic here](http://ham.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Perhaps you can [edit] to clarify how this question fits within the site's scope? Thanks!

Comment: Shortwave is a "technology of radio". Broadcasting doesn't always mean a commercial endeavour which suggests/recommends products. If you've actually heard SW you will rarely hear any "commercials". It's mostly talk, station ID and more talk. CNR/CIR gives language lessons for example. Give it a try. The broadcasts on the MW (medium wave) band (or AM band for those in the US) do have commercials.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Sorry about that. If I edited the question to ask how people "maintain a log" (of stations detected) would that be better? Public broadcasters are easier: with a known lat / long & broadcasting time. Contact with true "hams" comes later, when I gain the equipment (and license!) to transmit.

Comment: @AlanCampbell Unfortunately as it stands, your edit doesn't help at all. You now seem to be asking **three** distinct questions: how to identify potential broadcast stations for broadcast short-wave listening, how to maintain a listening log that can later be expanded into a transmission log as well, and whether people (I assume you mean radio amateurs) exchange cards post-contact. (continued)

Comment: The last is definitely on topic, the second may be on topic (depending much on how you phrase it such that it is sufficiently focused to be authoritatively answerable; it may be a duplicate, check the [logging](http://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logging) tag for helpful questions), and your first question remains the same. I would encourage you to post the latter two as two separate questions, distinct from this one, after checking that they haven't already been answered, and possibly rollback the edit.

Comment: @sessyargc.jp Technically, shortwave is a frequency range. (Strictly speaking known as HF; 3-30 MHz, corresponding to wavelengths of 100 down to 10 meters.) Just because a question involves the use of the radio spectrum doesn't make it on topic here; asking about the transceiver in a car RF key fob would be off topic as well, *unless* the question is framed in such a way as to be applicable to either amateur radio specifically, or radio *in general*. Please see the above-linked "What topics can I ask about here?" help center article which describes the topic scope of this site.

Answer (score 0):

[Radio Explorer](http://www.radioexplorer.com.ru/en/) purports that it can use the HFCC data directly (but I haven't tried it, because I use another tool named "eibiview"). Give it a spin and verify if it gives you what you need. 
 
 Some other resources that might be useful to you are the listings from [eibi](http://www.eibispace.de/) and [AOKI](http://www.geocities.jp/binewsjp/). ebiview can process these lists and also present you with what you require (or something close). eibiview can be downloaded at the eibi website above.

Comment: Radio Explorer is "free" software. Take note that if you are a serious SWLer/BCLer, one feature of Radio Explorer is not working correctly. Updating the solar information to predict MUF/LUF is not working.